# Active buttons in scrollview

Tags: xcode, button, scrollview, tableview

I have a source code where the main screen has 10 buttons (images buttons), each button is linked to sql database with tableview items, in the XIB I select which tag for each button, 1, 2, 3, 4..

I want make these buttons to scroll, how to do so?

I tried to convert the view into scrollview, then I have deleted the images, and created buttons in the scrollview, but now I do not know how to link each of the button to its tag in the tableview?

below is what I used:

@implementation mainViewController;

@synthesize master;
@synthesize model;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

  UIScrollView *scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
  scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
  scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
  scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
  [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
  scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,960);//You Can Edit this with your require
  scrollview.pagingEnabled=YES;

  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
  [button addTarget:self  action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
  [button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);

  UIImageView*   imageview1 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c1@2x.png"]];
  imageview1.frame=CGRectMake(18.0, 18, 285,50);
  [scrollview addSubview:imageview1];

  UIImageView*   imageview2 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c2@2x.png"]];
  imageview2.frame=CGRectMake(18.0, 78, 285,50);
  [scrollview addSubview:imageview2];

  UIImageView*   imageview3 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c3@2x.png"]];
  imageview3.frame=CGRectMake(18.0, 138, 285,50);
  [scrollview addSubview:imageview3];

  UIImageView*   imageview4 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"c4@2x.png"]];
  imageview4.frame=CGRectMake(18.0, 198, 285,50);
  [scrollview addSubview:imageview4];

Comment: Better approach would be to use UICollectionView if you have option.

Answer (score 0):

Assingn a tag to the button when you create it:

```
[buttonName setTag:1];
[buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(aMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Then use:

```
-(void)aMethod:(UIButton *)button {
 if ([button tag] == 1) {
  ...do something...
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.